# ¿Porque mi controlador no manda error 404 cuando quiere mostrar un modelo que no existe? laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, tailwind, 404

estoy creando una pagina web, instale alphine, laravel 10, livewire y tailwind, cree mis modelos, mis migraciones y todo, no modifique nada de la configuración de laravel, pero cuando empece a ahcer mis vistas show me percate que puedo entrar a las vistas sin que exista el modelo, me explico si yo entro a `miruta/proyectos/asasdasd` en la base de datos no hay ningun proyecto que tenga un Id asasdasd pero aun asi me deja entrar a la pagina sin sacar el error 404 por defecto cuando usas esta sintaxis:

```
    public function show(Proyect $proyect)
    {
       return view('proyect-show',compact('proyect'));
    }
```

lo unico que me regresa es un array vacio:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en antiguos proyectos que he hecho en laravel automaticamente si no existe un modelo este me regresa un 404 estas son mis rutas:

```
Route::get('/', IndexController::class);
Route::get('/proyecto/{proyecto}', [ProyectController::class,'show'])->name('proyect.show');
```

y este es mi modelo:

```
<?php

 namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

 class Proyect extends Model
{
use HasFactory;


public function tecnologies(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tecnology::class);
}

public function languages(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Language::class)->withPivot('framework_id');
}

public function links(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Link::class);
}
}
```

Comment: El nombre de la variable que inyectas en la funcion del controlador, tiene que ser el mismo que el del parametro en la ruta, pero en uno pusiste proyecto y en el otro proyect https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-model-binding